# Modify code to add top header ImageMagick

Tags: text, header, imagemagick-convert

Please some help here. I´m using IM 6.9.10-11 Q16 x86_64

The following coordinates correlative are related with the box number in input image. The first 3 lines in convert command create a
header text "Left - Right" that goes over the img2.png and img3.png

```
coord1="98x35+234+16" 
coord2="178x59+29+65"
coord3="178x59+223+65"
coord4="178x59+417+65"
coord5="178x59+611+65"
coord6="239x147+35+179" 
coord7="239x147+416+179"
coord8="239x147+73+349"
coord9="239x147+401+353"    
   
convert \
\( -size 125x36 xc:"#00137F" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Left" \) \
\( -size 125x36 xc:"#00137F" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Right" \) \
 -background white +smush +2 -write mpr:leftright +delete +gravity \
 \
input.png +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none -bordercolor "#870000"  \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord2 \)  \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord3 \)  \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord4 \)  \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord5 \)  \
-border 4 \( -clone 0,1 -smush -4 \) \( -clone 2,3 -smush -4 \) -delete 0-3 -gravity center +smush -4 +gravity \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord1 -border 4 \) +swap -gravity center -smush +12 +gravity -write Img1.png \
 \
\( \( mpr:img -crop $coord6 +repage -border 4 \) \( mpr:img -crop $coord7 +repage -border 4 \) \
   +smush +6 mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +11 +gravity  -write Img2.png  \) -delete 0--1 \
\
\( \( mpr:img -crop $coord8 +repage -border 4 \) \( mpr:img -crop $coord9 +repage -border 4 \) \
   +smush +6 mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +11 +gravity  -write Img3.png  \) null:
```

With this input.png

**input.png**

[image: enter link description here]

The code produces this 3 images.

**Img1.png**

[image: enter link description here]

**Img2.png**

[image: enter link description here]

**Img3.png**

[image: enter link description here]

What I´d like is to modify the current code to add a top header text to each one of these 3 images before they be created (before -write)
In order that the Img1, Img2 and Img3 be finally like this:

**Desired Img1**

[image: enter link description here]

**Desired Img2**

[image: enter link description here]

**Desired Img3**

[image: enter link description here]

I think I need to create the images first at the beginning of the convert command, something like this, but I don´t know how to adapt it and insert these lines within the current code.

```
\( -size 500x36 xc:"#757575" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Five boxes" \) \
\( -size 500x36 xc:"#757575" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Blue boxes" \) \
\( -size 500x36 xc:"#757575" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Green boxes" \) \
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick you can create images anywhere in parenthesis and reposition them with -swap ... (or +swap for the last two). So your command would become:

```
coord1="98x35+234+16" 
coord2="178x59+29+65"
coord3="178x59+223+65"
coord4="178x59+417+65"
coord5="178x59+611+65"
coord6="239x147+35+179" 
coord7="239x147+416+179"
coord8="239x147+73+349"
coord9="239x147+401+353"    

convert \
\( -size 125x36 xc:"#00137F" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold.ttf -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Left" \) \
\( -size 125x36 xc:"#00137F" -fill white -font Calibri-Bold.ttf -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Right" \) \
-background white +smush +2 -write mpr:leftright +delete +gravity \
\
input.png +repage -write mpr:img -delete 0--1 -background none -bordercolor "#870000"  \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord2 \)  \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord3 \)  \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord4 \)  \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord5 \)  \
-border 4 \( -clone 0,1 -smush -4 \) \( -clone 2,3 -smush -4 \) -delete 0-3 -gravity center +smush -4 +gravity \
\( mpr:img -crop $coord1 -border 4 \) +swap -gravity center -smush +12 +gravity \
\( -size 250x36 xc:gray -fill white -font Calibri-Bold.ttf -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Five Boxes" \) \
+swap -background none -gravity center -smush +20 +gravity -write Img1.png \
\
\( \( mpr:img -crop $coord6 +repage -border 4 \) \( mpr:img -crop $coord7 +repage -border 4 \) \
+smush +6 mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +11 +gravity  \
\( -size 250x36 xc:gray -fill white -font Calibri-Bold.ttf -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Blue Boxes" \) \
+swap -background none -gravity center -smush +20 +gravity -write Img2.png  \) -delete 0--1 \
\
\( \( mpr:img -crop $coord8 +repage -border 4 \) \( mpr:img -crop $coord9 +repage -border 4 \) \
+smush +6 mpr:leftright +swap -gravity center -smush +11 +gravity  \
\( -size 250x36 xc:gray -fill white -font Calibri-Bold.ttf -pointsize 32 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "Green Boxes" \) \
+swap -background none -gravity center -smush +20 +gravity -write Img3.png  \) null:
```

And the results are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, in IM 6 there is no way to know how wide your smushed colored images will be so as to make the title the same width unless you compute that ahead of time. In IM 7, it can be done in-line in your command line. So here I made it the same width as the two left right smushed images. You can change the width by changing the width value in -size 250x36.

Comment: Just great. Thanks so much one more time. I see that you didn't use "mpr" to create the top headers, then to create the Left-Right headers could be done in the same way? I mean without use  mpr? Additionally what does mean `-delete 0--1` and why sometimes use + or - gravity?

Comment: mpr: was needed to avoid repeatedly reading your input image. -delete 0--1 means to delete all the previous image in the command sequence 0 is the first and -1 is the last. So 0--1 means from the first to the last. -gravity is needed when setting a gravity for use. +gravity is used to reset the gravity to its default value. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/

Comment: I see. Many thanks for help, explanation and info shared.